# Connect Windows 10 license to installed Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, watermark, check-disk

I recently bought a new desktop that came with Windows 7 Pro. After upgrading to Windows 10 and installing an SSD by partitioning the hard drive and making an image of the most important part, I have been using it for a few weeks with no trouble.

However, I just installed a GPU, and there were initially some troubles as I installed it, including the Blue Screen Of Death. After checking the Stop Code and finding instructions on [this website](http://www.windowswally.com/how-to-fix-the-ntfs_file_system-error/) to fix it by performing a check on the drive, I was able to make it work again, but since then the lower right corner of my screen has looked like

[image: Watermark telling me to activate Windows]

I checked Settings, and it said that I have error code 0xC004f034. I clicked the option to check my computer for a license, and the option that I had changed hardware recently, and it confirmed that I had a license for Windows 10 Pro on this machine that was running Windows 10 Pro... and said that I should now install Windows 10 Pro.

At first it looked like I could sidestep reinstalling everything if I just signed in to a Microsoft-affiliated account such as Skype, but I stopped pursuing that option when it became clear that I would then have a Microsoft account connected with this computer, and that my computer account password would be changed to that Microsoft password.

So, I'm now wondering if I can fix this problem of a watermark that tells me to activate Windows without being coerced to put a Microsoft account into Windows, spending money or reinstalling Windows.

Some specs about the Windows I have installed are:

[image: Windows version specifications]

As suggested, I ran ShowKeyPlus, and it shows an installed key as well as an original key.

Comment: You will have to activate your installation by calling the MS activation center for your region phone

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  The entire paragraph about SuperUser is extremely confusing.

Comment: Some of the information that isn’t required to answer this question.  A screenshot that indicates you actually currently have Windows 10 Professional installed, which build of Windows 10 you have installed, written confirmation that ShowKeyPlus displays your Windows 7 license key.

Comment: @Ramhound "Some of the information that isn't required to answer this question" - what do you mean by that? Grammatically, I'd guess that you were about to list things I mentioned which were superfluous, but what you list are things I haven't mentioned. I'll look for the things you listed.

Comment: I was listening what I needed to know to answer this question but wrote isn’t instead of **is** which is sort of obvious in the context of the second comment I made.  Did you try an activate your installation by phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an elevated command prompt run the command: `slmgr /upk`

This will remove the product key from the system and allow you to enter a new product key.

Proceed to the activate windows screen again, and enter the Windows 7 product key from the original license you had. This should be located on an OEM sticker on the computer or with the the installation media you purchased.